# wso2 API Endpoint creation failed: 404 ressource not found

Tags: postgresql, rest, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to create a REST API with [wso2 API_Manager](https://wso2.com/api-management/) to gather data from a **Postgres** database (learning purpose). I struggle doing so and I would like to know whether:

- I did not understand wso2 components' roles properly (new techno and subject for me)
- or there is an error in the way I configured the manager.

### System setup

I used this [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am), added postgres jdbc jar in `/repository/components/lib/` and added the following in `/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml`:

```xml
<datasource>
     <name>s0m3dAtabas3</name>
     <description>The db used for testing purposes</description>
     <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
           <url>jdbc:postgresql://sandor_postgres:5432/s0m3dAtabas3</url>
           <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
           <username>s0m3us3rfr0mdAtAMaj0r</username>
           <password>N0t5uchAs1mple1</password>
           <maxActive>80</maxActive>
           <minIdle>5</minIdle>
           <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
           <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
           <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
           <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
     </definition>
</datasource>
```

I made sure than the postgres' container named `sandor_postgres` is accessible from wso2's with these credentials. In this database, I have a **table** called `something`. The image comes with the following UIs:

- admin
- publisher
- store

### Graphical API creation

I first followed the *WorldBank tutorial* which seemed crystal clear (though I am not quite sure where the data came from). I then tried to adapt it.

#### Step 1: Design

I used the database name as context (`s0m3dAtabas3`) v.1.0.0. Since the table is called `something`, the url pattern I end up with is `/s0m3dAtabas3/1.0.0/something`

#### Step 2: Implement

This is where things start to be confusing. No matter the resource path I use in the **Endpoint** (end point type REST), I get a 404 and the logs are not very helpful

- `http://192.168.8.111:8280` -> 404
- `http://192.168.8.111:8280/something` -> 404
- `http://192.168.8.111:9443/tried_several` -> Invalid - Error connecting to backend
- `http://192.168.8.111:8243/tried_several` -> Invalid - Error connecting to backend

```
INFO - InboundDBSyncRequestEvent Running DB sync task.
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /s0m3dAtabas3/1.0.0
INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-10-29 11:42:31,030+0000]
INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-10-29 11:42:31,197+0000]
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /s0m3dAtabas3/bullshit
INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-10-29 11:48:30,649+0000]
INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-10-29 11:48:30,790+0000]
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /
INFO - InboundDBSyncRequestEvent Running DB sync task.
INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /
```

Did I miss some **important configuration step** or wso2 API Manager is not the **standalone component** I thought it was and requires another component to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a misunderstanding in the concept-wise.

Here is the basic idea of a typical API Management solution.

You have a web service (REST, SOAP, etc...) which you need to expose as a managed API. Now, you can front your service with API Manager and expose it as a managed API with security, rate limiting, managed life cycle etc.

In your case, it seems you don't have such a service, but only have a database table. So, before using API Manager to front your service, you first need to expose your table as a service. For that purpose, I'd suggest you use the data service component of [WSO2 EI 7.0.0](https://wso2.com/integration/). See [1] for how to do that. Once you have your service ready, you can use API Manager to expose it as a managed API.

[1] https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/sending-a-simple-message-to-a-datasource/